# Clean Invoke patterns?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Right now, I have a windows application (C#) that spits out long running reports.  Each report grabs some information from the UI to constrain the reports. Of course, the report creation happens on a background thread and I need to properly invoke the various controls to get things like selected indexes and values.  But I don't think my code looks good and was hoping there was a better pattern.  Because there are so many requests to controls, I made generic delegates for each type that would be returned:

```
private delegate string StringDelegate();
private delegate int IntDelegate();
```

Further down, there are various instantiations of these delegates:

```
private StringDelegate GetYearSelectedItem = new StringDelegate(cmbYearAsync);
```

YearAsync looks like this:

```
private string cmbYearAsync() {
    return cmbYear.SelectedItem.ToString();
}
```

And finally, in code that is on a background thread, this is how I get the values:

```
cmbYear.Invoke(GetCmbYearSelectedItem);
```

Is there a cleaner way of getting these values from a separate thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to go with the threaded design (perhaps you want the background threads to report partial results to the UI as they run?), if you have C# 3 you can certainly neaten it up a little. Some people find an extension method like this helpful:

```
public static class ControlExtensions
{
    public static T Invoke<T>(this Control ctrl, Func<T> func)
    {
        if (ctrl.InvokeRequired)
            return (T) ctrl.Invoke(func);

        return func();
    }
}
```

As well as checking whether the call needs to be marshalled, it also makes the delegate parameter typesafe. So you can write:

```
string selected = comboBox1.Invoke(() => comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

No need to pre-declare all that other stuff. Just write the usual code you'd write but inside that lambda pattern.

You can write a similar extension method that takes `Action` instead of `Func<T>`, and returns `void`, for operations that don't need a return value.

Answer (score 4):

## short answer

Don't do that ;-)

## long answer

gather the report parameters from the UI controls up front (perhaps in a small class) and pass them to the reports in the background threads

This eliminates the cross-thread calls to the UI controls, and decouples the report parameters from the user-interface